# TYPO3 9.5.4 (with slug) ignores get parameter 'type'

Tags: typo3, yaml, typoscript, slug, typo3-9.x

I want to switch the type of my typo3 website e.g. for xml or json output, but the system ignores the get parameter type. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if there is a bug.

typoscript example

```
testtype = PAGE
testtype.typeNum = 13
testtype.10 = TEXT
testtype.10.value = test
testtype.config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1
```

my site config

https://pastebin.com/UsdZGq7N

Comment: I remember that this was discussed in Slack. As soon as you define `PageType`  enhancer, you have to define all types there or they will be ignored. So add `13` there and it should work :)

Comment: But how should we deal with multiple page types with the same url / url suffix? It's common to use `/path-to-site/` for the whole html document and get the correspondending ajax response variant, when calling `/path-to-site/?type=13` The topic is also discussed at https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87104

Answer (score 2):

You make use of the PageType routeEnhancer, when that is active you have to map all the page-types you use. Otherwise it gets stripped from the url.

Also, the PageType routeEnhancer should be the last enhancer you configure, as it modifies existing route variants:
https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Routing/Enhancer/PageTypeDecorator.php#L25